# Database Is lost when Docker Container is stopped. How to recover?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following compose file, from [this project](https://github.com/paulobfsilva123/covidoff-web):

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  static-files:
    driver: local
  postgres:
    driver: local

services:
    db:
      image: postgres:11.1
      volumes:
        - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      env_file:
        - ./config/environment/development.env
      expose:
        - "5432"

    webapp:
      build:
        context: webapp
      volumes:
        - ./webapp/covidoff:/srv/covidoff
        - static-files:/srv/static-files
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
        - "80:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
      env_file:
        - ./config/environment/development.env
```

As you can see, there are two services being launched: a PostgreSQL database `db` and a Django `webapp`. Everything is working well so far, except for one thing: every time I stop the `db` container the data is lost.

Someone told me to try `postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data` instead of `postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`, but that didn't work either.

The problem is: this server is already live and with data. How can I solve the persistence problem and still keep the current data?

Some progress. A simple change made it so that the data persists after the container is stopped, I'm just not sure why. I replaced this:

```
PGDATA=pgdata
```

With this:

```
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

In my `env` file. But why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker volume driver is not persisting your data between restarts of services. You can use the [local-persist driver](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist) ; I have used this several times for this use case.

When you already have the data somewhere you can create the volume before starting the services and copy your data to the specified directory. Postgres should pick up the database from there.

Comment: Great, thanks! You know how I can create the volume before starting the services?

Comment: That’s described on the GitHub page. After installing the driver simply call: docker volume create -d local-persist -o mountpoint=/Data/path —name=volume_name

Comment: Thank you! I'll give a try

Comment: I already managed to use persistence (see my edit), but I'm not sure about the second step. How do I do that?

Comment: `PGDATA` in your environment file overwrites the data directory postgres uses to store its data. `PGDATA=pgdata` seems to be nowhere, so the data was not persisted.  You wrote that the server was already live and you have data? you can either export that (create a database dump) or copy the content of this installation to the newly created directory of the postgres container. A database dump is preferred here

Comment: Got it. So just `pgdata` doesn't map anywhere? The data must liver somewhere, right? Couldn't I just copy that volume, wherever it is?

Comment: But yes, I'm working on a data dump. Just want to know what my options are.

Comment: I recovered data before by simply copying the data/volume to a new database installation, but that is not the desired way. If you have the chance to export the data, go ahead with that way! Thats the 'normal' and supported solution